# Как отрезать кусок массива с помощью цикла for?

Tags: python

Мой массив состоит из 0 и 1. Нужно найти 0, которые находятся рядом друг с другом и посчитать: если количество 0 больше определенного числа, отрезать этот кусок в массиве и искать следующий такой же кусок. В конце вывести массив. Вот (псевдо, так как не работает и ничего не выводит)код:

```
for b in range (0, len(binarr)):
     if binarr[b] == 0:
            while binarr[b] != 1:
                b+=1
                for u in range (0, b):
                    if u > 5:
                        binarr.append('PAUSE')
                        #binarr.remove(u)
print(binarr)
```

Comment: Судя по названиям переменных, вы работаете с строками из 0/1, приведите изначальную задачу.

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста свою задачу подробнее. Что значит "отрезать этот кусок в массиве и искать следующий"? Вы привели пример кода. Что он делает не так? Какое поведение вы ожидаете? Приведите пример значений, которые должны быть выведены, например: "У меня есть список `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, я хочу, чтобы после выполнения моего кода выводился список `[1, 3, 5`], но сейчас выводится `[2, 4]`"